# Compiler for dart

Tags: dart, compiler-construction

Is there any editor for dart.
I was trying to run my dart program at vscode it runs but did not print anything.
I was trying to take input from user and add it into a list of numbers and then show the list on console.
It takes the input but did not shown any list.

```
// Importing dart:io file
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  List<int> list = [5];

  // Scanning number
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    int? n = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
    list.add(n);
  }
  // Here ? and ! are for null safety

  // Printing that number
  print("Your list $list");
}
```

Comment: You created an infinite loop. `i` is always less than `list.length` because every iteration of the loop you add an element to the list increasing the length by 1.

Comment: How to solve it?
Can you explain please?

Comment: The core issue is that your loop condition `i < list.length` always results in `true`. Every time through the loop you are increasing the value of BOTH `i` AND `list.length` by `1`. So the first time through the loop you are comparing `0 < 1`, then on the next iteration `1 < 2`, then `2 < 3`, etc. Your condition needs to eventually result in `false` for the loop to terminate.